# Wordpress plugin to display facebook posts from a page?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want the look like youtube except instead of videos there will be posts from Facebook. The latest post titles will be displayed and when user clicks on one, the post will be displayed as embedded. Any idea which plugin will do this for me?

Comment: You should at least try something before coming on here and asking what to use. You are not asking a question regarding a problem, you are asking for a full solution

Comment: I have tried a lot of plugins but none fits the requirement

Answer (score 0):

To get the level of customization that you want I would start by looking at what's already out there. I found some good resources at http://designscrazed.org/wordpress-facebook-plugins/. Notably, "Custom Facebook Feed". Hopefully this helps get you started.